# Android simulate touch on other program

Tags: java, android, touch, simulate

As u know, there are many solutions and codes on stackoverflow for simulating touch on your own app you are developing.

So my question is that i wanna touch a view on other application with my own application.

How can we do this?

Just imagine i wanna click on X,Y position of the screen each X seconds.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wanna take control of other application from your own application? You can't do it.

Comment: @Anton can u leave a URL please?

Comment: @galvan no making controll really. just click on X , Y position !

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't.

You are welcome to write an `AccessibilityService`. However, this has only limited ability to manipulate other apps, and it requires users to not only install your app but agree to allow your app to have wide access to all their existing app's UIs.

Comment: But, i think its possible. the user will install the app, and we do not need to access the codes and xml ids of that app. if we be able to make to widget to bring it over other apps and set a timer for example each 2 second, the object behind of the widget will be clicked.

Comment: @Bana: "is that possible to write code for that u think?" -- fortunately, that is not possible, for obvious security reasons, except on rooted devices.

Comment: What are the restrictions for using accessibility service?